# GCP CloudSQL increasing massive size of storage day by day

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I wonder storage size of the MySQL Cloud SQL server in GCP is increased in TBs over time in just 4-5 days from just a few GB. I have checked the size of all the databases but that's also not increased.
Also, I checked the log files size using the query:

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

which is also not that high in storage.

If anyone knows what could be the issue.? Thanks.

Comment: Did you enabled point in time recovery recently?

Comment: It was already enabled.